# Bing map upgrade v7 to v8: What should be used in place of Microsoft.Maps.Overlays.Style (as this is deprecated now)

Tags: bing-maps

```
  Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Overlays.Style', {
            callback: _getMap
        });
```

I have this code where in after loading this particular module I call the _getMap function which loads a map successfully.

However, in v8 Bing maps have deprecated this module and haven't provided any clear indication of it's replacement. Can anyone please help me find a replacement for the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Overlays module in V7 was primarily used for a better navigation bar layout for mobile. In V8 there are three built in navigation bar options, all are well suited for mobile, so no longer need for a module for this. Simply remove the module loading code with this:

`_getMap();`

You can find information about the built in navigation bars here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt736390.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I did the same & it works good. Not able to load pushpins now since many of the pushpins properties have also been deprecated.

Comment: The following options are deprecated: height, width, htmlContent, state, infobox, typeName, zIndex. Note most of these where for the Bing theme module which is deprecated. The main one here is htmlContent. There are a lot of other ways to create pushpins in V8, but if you want to use HTML there is a module for that in a code sample here: http://bingmapsv8samples.azurewebsites.net/#Html%20Pushpin%20Layer